# Finding language in string (doing substring?) with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, substring

I have a table with languages which s_name value looks like this:

```
'en_UK'
'en_US'
'de_CH'
'de_AT'
```

I want to get all the distinct languages, without the country part. So for example, in case I just had those of the example, I would need to get:

```
en
de
```

What would be the best way of doing so?

I have this right now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(name,1,2) 
FROM my_languages
```

Comment: I think that is probably the best way of getting that value.  It is not working in some way. Your code works see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3301f/1

Comment: are the name always contain 2 letters (*langauge*) before the underscore symbol?

Comment: Did you try your code :-) ?

Comment: bonCodigo: Yes, and it works. I was just thinking of a better way of doing so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '_', 1) langName 
FROM my_languages
```

**OR**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '_', 1) langName 
FROM my_languages 
GROUP BY langName
```

Check this link [**MySQL STRING Functions**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way:

```
select distinct left(s_name, 2)
from t
```

This assumes the language name is the left two characters.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in Oracle as well as in MySql I think:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('en_UK',INSTR('en_UK','_')+1) country FROM dual
/
```